# How to create custom dropdown list in react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I almost consume 17 hours, but the answers on what I have searched did not satisfy the exact answer to my question,

**how to create own custom DropdownList in react native?** I already did, the 1st child node which is DropDown (cyan) is work properly, the 2nd child node which is the the List (green) with absolute position but it was not work properly, unless the root parent (red) will also covered the 2nd child node with absolute position, to make it active and clickable, as like what I mention from the picture, *Figure 1.0*

[image]

I set absolute position of the List (green) to make it float from the next child node and the error was persist, the List(parent) was disabled and it cannot click each child items (yellow), unless I set height of the root parent (red) that covered the entire child node but it leads to the next node to adjust the position and do the unexpected layout, like the sample picture *Figure 1.1*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I DID IT!, the problem is the root parent (red) must not have customized styled property, and I still have one questions, I dont know if it is bug or what, once I did not put any custom property in the style of root parent it works properly, and here is my source code

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Separator from './Separator';
import Spinner from './Spinner';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';

export default function () {

  const [spBusiness, setSPBusiness] = useState({
    showList: false,
    selectedItem: ''
  })

  const onShowList = () => {
    if (spBusiness.showList) {
      setSPBusiness(prev => ({
        ...prev,
        showList: false
      }))
    }
    else {
      setSPBusiness(prev => ({
        ...prev,
        showList: true
      }))
    }
  }
  const onSelectItem = (item, index) => {
    setSPBusiness(prev => ({
      showList: false,
      selectedItem: item
    }));
  }

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
      <Box text='Rectangle 1' onPress={() => console.log('Rect 1')} />
      <Separator vertical={1} />
      <Spinner
        placeholder='Select Item'
        items={['A', 'B', 'C']}
        isListShow={spBusiness.showList}
        selectedItem={spBusiness.selectedItem}
        onShowList={onShowList}
        onSelectItem={onSelectItem}
      />
      <Separator vertical={1} />
      <Box text='Rectangle 2' onPress={() => console.log('Rect 2')} />
      <Separator vertical={1} />
    </View>
  )
}

const Box = props => (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onPress} style={{ zIndex: -1, borderRadius: 7.5, width: 250, height: 45, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: '#242424' }}>
    <Text style={{ color: '#fff' }}>{props.text}</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
)
```

DropDownList/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './style';
import AIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';

import {
    View,
    Text,
    Dimensions,
    TouchableOpacity,
    ScrollView
} from 'react-native';
import Separator from '../Separator';

export default function (props) {

    const { items } = props;

    const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');
    const size = size => (size / 100) * width;
    const hp = hp => (hp / 100) * height;
    const wp = wp => (wp / 100) * width;

    return (
        <View>
            {/* here is the root parent with empty style property*/}
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.skin}
                activeOpacity={0.75}
                onPress={props.onShowList}
            >
                <View style={styles.body}>
                    <View style={styles.upperBodyPane}>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.centerBodyPane}>
                        {props.selectedItem.length === 0 &&
                            <Text>{props.placeholder}</Text>
                        }
                        {props.selectedItem.length !== 0 &&
                            <Text>{props.selectedItem}</Text>
                        }
                        <AIcon name='caretdown' size={size(3.5)} color='#242424' />
                    </View>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            {props.isListShow &&
                <ScrollView
                    style={styles.list}
                    contentContainerStyle={styles.listContainer}
                >
                    {
                        items.map((item, index) => (
                            <View key={index}>
                                <Item
                                    item={item}
                                    onPress={() => props.onSelectItem(item, index)}
                                />
                                {items.length !== (index + 1) ? <Separator vertical={0.5} /> : null}
                            </View>
                        ))
                    }
                </ScrollView>
            }
        </View>
    )
}

const Item = props => (
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.item} onPress={props.onPress}>
        <Text style={styles.itemText}>{props.item}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
)
```

DropDownList/style.js

```
import {
    Dimensions,
    StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');
const size = size => (size / 100) * width;
const hp = hp => (hp / 100) * height;
const wp = wp => (wp / 100) * width;

export default StyleSheet.create({
    skin: {
        minWidth: wp(70),
        height: hp(5.5),
        paddingHorizontal: wp(6),
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'cyan',
        position: 'relative'
    },
    body: {
    },
    centerBodyPane: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
    },
    item: {
        height: hp(5),
        paddingHorizontal: wp(5),
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'orange',
    },
    itemText: {
        color: 'white'
    },
    list: {
        top: hp(6.5),
        width: wp(70),
        maxHeight: hp(15),
        backgroundColor: 'green',
        position: 'absolute',
    },
    listContainer: {
        padding: size(1.75),
    }
})
```

but the worse case only, I need to set the next child node of DropDownList to `zIndex: -1` , but it finally works.